# The handler for the route is invalid - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, routes

I am trying to create a custom REST API endpoint in WordPress using Classes. I've also done the same the traditional way - which worked just fine. However, using classes I am getting an error `The handler for the route is invalid`.

The code:

```
class CSS_Ads {

    var $url;
    var $endpointPrefix;
    var $endpointName;

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('rest_api_init', array( $this, 'ads_api_route' ) );
    }

    public function ads_api_route() {
        register_rest_route( $this->endpointPrefix, $this->endpointName,
            array(
                'methods'  => 'GET',
                'callback' => 'get_all_ads_api_endpoint'
            )
        );
    }

    public function get_all_ads_api_endpoint($params) {
        // doing my post query and stuff
    }

}
```

Setting:

```
$ads = new CSS_Ads();
$ads->url = get_site_url();
$ads->endpointPrefix = 'bs/v1';
$ads->endpointName = 'ads';
```

Full error:

```
{"code":"rest_invalid_handler","message":"The handler for the route is invalid","data":{"status":500}}
```

The query is set to -1, there is only one post on the website so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the callback is not reaching the function.

Solved the issue with the extra function below:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // Add custom REST API endpoint
    add_action('rest_api_init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\ads_api_route' );
}

// REST API route
public function ads_api_route() {
    register_rest_route( 'my_endpoint/v1', '/ads',
        array(
            'methods'  => 'GET',
                'callback' => [$this, 'get_all_ads_api_endpoint']
            )
    );
}

function init_rest_api_endpoint() {
    $endpoint = new restAPIendpoint();
    $endpoint->ads_api_route();
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'init_rest_api_endpoint' );
```

Hope this helps someone in future :)

Comment: This is nice, thank you. The `$this` is very important. Again, thanks.