# "rest_invalid_handler","message":"The handler for the route is invalid"

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

So I'm wanting to register a new route in WordPress and for some reason, it's giving me the following error:

```
{"code":"rest_invalid_handler","message":"The handler for the route is invalid","data":{"status":500}}
```

Here is the code that I have inside `functions.php` - I checked a lot of guides and each one keeps describing the callback return to be `'callback' => [$this, 'get_o365_menu'],` but since I'm not inside a class, I can't return it.

Please keep in mind that inside the `functions.php` file, I have a namespace as "Test\Main`". I've tried all attempts and can't get a return.

```
function get_o365_menu()
{
    $posts = get_posts([
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'post_type' => 'employee',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ]);
    var_dump($posts);

    if ($posts) {
        $employee_ids = [];
        foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
            $employee_post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_octopus_id', true);
            $employee_ids[$employee_post_meta] = $post->ID;
        }
        echo json_encode($employee_ids);
    }
}

// Register rest route
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'merge', 'script', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_o365_menu',
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a / in the route definition

```
function get_o365_menu()
{
    $posts = get_posts([
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'post_type' => 'employee',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ]);
    var_dump($posts);

    if ($posts) {
        $employee_ids = [];
        foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
            $employee_post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_octopus_id', true);
            $employee_ids[$employee_post_meta] = $post->ID;
        }
        echo json_encode($employee_ids);
    }
}

// Register rest route
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'merge', '/script', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_o365_menu',
    ]);
});
```

http://.../wp-json/merge/script

Comment: For more info on this check this page https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/ it comes with some examples as well

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it's still coming back with the same error @Jasper, I wonder if there needs to be specific permission callbacks also.

Comment: should not need to, I copy pasted your code when I tested it and got back an empty array (as employee is not a post type in my test site). Depending on the settings you may need to send an authentication header.

Comment: maybe this solution works ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65027131/the-handler-for-the-route-is-invalid-wordpress